# Entity Framework Core - Foreign Key 1 (extra foreign key column)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-model-first

I just upgraded to Entity Framework Core 2 and now I'm getting issues with an extra column existing and having a unique key even though it's not in my model and it's not defined anywhere else.

The index:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Vouchers",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
        Code = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
        IsClaimed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
        LastModified = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
        NumberOfUnits = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        TransactionId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        TransactionId1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true) // why is this here?
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Vouchers", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Vouchers_Transactions_TransactionId1",
            column: x => x.TransactionId1,
            principalTable: "Transactions",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    });
```

TransactionId1 isn't in the model:

```
public class Voucher : IAutoLastModified
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfUnits { get; set; }
    public Guid Code { get; set; }
    public bool IsClaimed { get; set; }
}
```

Am I defining the Foreign Key wrongly?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Voucher>().HasOne(x => x.Transaction).WithOne(x => x.Voucher).IsRequired(false);
```

My app fails because TransactionId1 is always going to be null and has a unique constraint that I can't remove.

Why did EF create an extra column for this table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so I figured out what the issue was (keeping the question here for anyone who makes the same mistake I did).

I marked the relationship as Optional but the column was an `int` instead of `int?` so EF decided to add it's own column behind the scenes.

After fixing this I had to recreate the database - migration did not complete successfully due to existing data.

Answer (score 11):

This might also happen if you define your models two way binded but forget to use it in fluent:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders {get; set;}
}

public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Guid Customer { get; set; }
}

// AppDbContext
builder.Entity<Order>()
     .HasOne(x => x.Customer) // <-- EDIT: Also use it like this, not .HasOne<Customer>()
     .WithMany() //WRONG -> should be .WithMany(x => x.Orders) OR modify the model to not define the collection at the customer entity
     .HasForeignKey(x => x.CustomerId)
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
;
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent almost a day, and would have spent even more, this was helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when the type of foreign key field in the child was not matching with the type of primary key field in the parent.

**Example:**

```
public class User // Parent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserLike> UserLikes { get; set; } // Child collection
}

public class UserLike // Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; } // Foreign key
    public virtual User User { get; set; } // Navigation property
}
```

In the **DbContext**, I had:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserLike>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(x => x.User)
    .WithMany(x => x.UserLikes)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
}
```

Here, `int UserId` does not match with the type of primary key `long Id` in the parent. The solution is to make the `UserId` `long`:

```
public class UserLike // Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; } // Foreign key
    public virtual User User { get; set; } // Navigation property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the model builder which column in your `voucher` table you want to use as the foreign key column. Otherwise Entity Framework will just create one for you.

To do this, add a `HasForeignKey` method to the fluent setup:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Voucher>().HasOne(x => x.Transaction).WithOne(x => x.Voucher).HasForeignKey<Voucher>(x => x.TransactionId).IsRequired(false);
```

Note when setting up a one-to-one relationship, you need to define the entity the foreign key exists in as a generic constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue in the past using Data first approach. I had to delete an existing column but after every update that column appears in the edmx schema structure which I had to manually delete to make it work. can you recreate the edmx instead of update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the fix for me was to add the DataAnnotation tag of [ForeignKey("")] above the navigation property to explicitly state which one to use.

```
public Guid TransactionId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("TransactionId ")]
public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
```

Thanks